# How to write µ into a text file using Python

Tags: python, file

I am making a GUI for Quiz software. It works like it takes input for a question and adds it as a line into a text file it goes simple for other texts but for the special character it gets complicated and gives encoding or codec error which you can see below:

```
write() argument must be str, not bytes

#This is when I tried to encode it o utf-8 and then add it to file
```

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b8' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

#This is when I don't encode
```

The code which I am using is given below, please help if you have some solution.

```
            try:
                Question=QuestionEntry.get()+':'+correct+'|'+str([OptionEntry1.get(),OptionEntry2.get(),OptionEntry3.get(),OptionEntry4.get()])+'|'+str(Time)+'|'+str(image)
            except:
                Question=QuestionEntry.get()+':'+correct+'|'+str([OptionEntry1.get(),OptionEntry2.get(),OptionEntry3.get(),OptionEntry4.get()])+'|'+str(Time)
            
            print(Question)
            
            chapFile=open(str(chapter.get())+'.txt','a')
            chapFile.write(Question)

            chapFile.close()
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: `with open('file.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f: f.write('µ')`

Comment: What does doing this change @deceze? Is opening the file in both ways different?

Comment: The deciding factor here is probably the `encoding` parameter. The `with` is merely best practice instead of a manual `.close()`.